# Split names into first and last and insert into existing first Name column and last Name column sql

Tags: mysql, pymysql

I have a table where a column is named `CustomerName` that contains first name, middle initial and last name.  Some names might not have a middle initial.  In the same table, i have 3 columns named `firstName`, `middleName` and `LastName` thats populated with None values.  I need to split the `CustomerName` column and put them in respective columns.  How would I do that in `mysql`?  I tried the following but get error:

```
UPDATE xcust SET
LastName = SUBSTRING_INDEX(trim(CustomerName),' ',-1) 
case 
when LENGTH(trim(CustomerName)) - LENGTH(REPLACE(trim(CustomerName), ' ', 
'')) = 1 then null
else  MiddleName = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(trim(CustomerName),' 
',2),' ',-1) 
end
FirstName = SUBSTRING_INDEX(trim(CustomerName),' ',1)
where CustomerName = 'JAMES G STAHL'"""
```

The ***error*** i receive is:

> ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'case \nwhen LENGTH(trim(CustomerName)) -
>   LENGTH(REPLACE(trim(CustomerName), ' ', ' at line 3")

Im using pymysql to run the query.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested, but at first glance you are missing commas between the different values you are setting and need to take MiddleName outside of the case statement.

```
UPDATE xcust SET
LastName = SUBSTRING_INDEX(trim(CustomerName),' ',-1),
MiddleName = 
    case when LENGTH(trim(CustomerName)) - LENGTH(REPLACE(trim(CustomerName), ' ', '')) = 1 then
        null
    else
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(trim(CustomerName),' ',2),' ',-1)
    end,
FirstName = SUBSTRING_INDEX(trim(CustomerName),' ',1)
where CustomerName = 'JAMES G STAHL'
```

Comment: Make sure to hit the check mark to mark it as solved also :)

Comment: I did  do that :)

Comment: You voted it up but didn't mark it as the answer it seems. Not sure about the -1 on your question though. Wasn't from me. Guess someone thought it was a lazy question or something heh